# If / else in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if/else function for a simple game but I'm new to coding.

```
Chapters = 0;

Books = 0;

Pens = 1;

WarehouseRoom = 50;
function ChaptersUp(number) {
    if (Pens > 0) {
        if ((Chapters + number) <= 9) {
          Chapters = Chapters + number;
          document.getElementById("Chapters").innerHTML = Chapters;
        } 
        else {
            ChaptersOver = (Chapters + number - 10);
            if (Books < WarehouseRoom) {
                if (ChaptersOver <= 9) {
                    Books = Books + 1;
                    Chapters = ChaptersOver;
                    document.getElementById("Chapters").innerHTML = Chapters;
                    document.getElementById("Books").innerHTML = Books;
                } 
                else {
                    BooksOver = Math.floor(ChaptersOver / 10);
                    Books = Books + BooksOver + 1;
                    Chapters = (ChaptersOver - (BooksOver * 10));
                    document.getElementById("Chapters").innerHTML = Chapters;
                    document.getElementById("Books").innerHTML = Books;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I want the function to run up to the point where the Warehouse is full. Currently, if I add 11 Books (110 Chapters) at a time, the function will stop operating at 55 books, but I've already went over the limit.

**Question :** How can I make it stop at exactly the amount equal to WarehouseRoom?

Comment: Hi Nikki. Your code is incomplete and it's impossible to understand. Anyway, since you're saying you're a beginner, here's an advice: Open your browser debugging tools (Probably F12 on your keyboard, but that may vary), and learn how to use that. It will be much more helpful to you if you do that than if someone helps you with you immediate question. Good Luck!

Comment: Calculate `(WarehouseRoom - Books) * 10`, that's the number of chapters you have room for. If `number` is higher than this, reduce it to this amount.

Answer (score -1):

You should try a for statment.

```
for(int i = 1; i > warehouseFull; i++)
    {
    }
```

i is used to for the repeat and the loop will repeat till it is equal to warehouseFull. The i++ on the end is there so that once the loop is done it adds 1 to i. You could do the same backwards if you lose x amount of books. also you don't have to declare i inside the for statesmen but if you are going to use many for statement then it will make it easier so you don't have to switch letters or declare i = 0;.

Comment: `int i` should be `var i`. This is Javascript, not C.

Comment: when i was in java i never used var and in fact im using java in spring its still int.

Comment: Eclipse, greenfoot, python, java all use the same thing int.

Comment: The question was about `JavaScript` and **not** `Java`. JavaScript uses `var` for all variables.